# My DISTINCT SQL query taking long time to execute in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, group-by, distinct, postgresql-9.4

I have more than 50 million rows and its taking hours to get this query done:

```
select distinct column_1
from table_1
where "colour" = 'red';
```

I tried this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (
   SELECT "column_1"
   FROM   table_1
   where "colour" = 'red'
   ORDER  BY "column_1"
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT l."column_1"
   FROM   cte c
   ,      LATERAL (   
      SELECT "column_1"
      FROM  table_1
      WHERE  "column_1" > c."column_1" and "colour" = 'red'
      ORDER  BY "column_1"
      LIMIT  1
      ) l
   )
SELECT *
FROM cte;
```

I tried this one too:

```
select column_1
from table_1
where "colour" = 'red'
group by column_1 ;
```

All queries are taking more time. Is there any other way?

Comment: What indexes and keys do you have? What % of rows are likley to be red? A distinct operation requires sorted data, an index on colour, Column_1 would be beneficial

Comment: I tried the indexing as well, still taking more time to execute. Almost 20% of columns will be red!

Comment: But what indexes did you try? An index on (colour)? An index on (colour, column_1)? An index on (column_1, colour)?

Comment: Please update your question with the output of EXPLAIN for the SQL statement you are actually trying to run. FYI including 3 different SQL statements in your question is more confusing than helpful